# Lock menu item when window open, unlock when closing

Tags: c#, wpf, menu

I have a window that I want to allow only one instance of it to be open at a time.  They can open / close the window, but can't have multiple copies *of the same window* open at a time.

I have a menu with an option that when clicked, opens the ProductSelection window.  ListProductList is my button:

```
private void ListProductListCanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
  e.CanExecute = _productListCanExecute;
  //_productListCanExecute = !_productListCanExecute;
}

private void ListProductList(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
  _productListCanExecute = false;
  ProductSelection pl = new ProductSelection(productCategoryList, productStyleList, productList);
  pl.Show();
}
```

Notice that I set the e.CanExecute of the ListProductList button to false to ensure that the event handler doesn't run and therefore doesn't open more windows.

Now, how can I detect that the ProductSelection window has closed in order to set the _productListCanExecute back to true?  It's not a modal window, because I want to allow them to do other things.

Comment: You'll probably have to expound on this a bit: unlock what menu?  Which window is closed?  Is the menu on the same window that closed... ?  Probably a bit more code would help.

Comment: I have one WPF window that when I choose a menu option from a tool bar I lock that option so that there is only on instance. The second window is opened by calling ListProductList, this then locks the window by setting the e.canExecute (these are linked through a commandbinding. Basically if you open a window if it is closed can some code be forced to be executed such as would happen in a finally clause of try-catch.

Comment: Are you trying to force the ListProductList to essentially be a modal windows?  In other words, once that is shown you don't want the user to do anything else until this window is closed?

Comment: No, that can be done with showDialog() I want them to only have one instance of this window open but be able to do other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest solution here is to make the pl variable a global.

Whenever the button is clicked, just "show" that existing window.